# ReactNative; Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) after using AdmobBanner

Tags: react-native, admob

I try to add addmob banner to my code but I got an error "Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function(for composite components) but got undefine." After I using Admob (reference from https://blog.expo.dev/adding-admob-to-your-expo-project-aa4e48ac848)

```
import { AdMobBanner, AdMobInterstitial, AdMobRewarded } from "expo";

export default function Quest() {
 
    function bannerError() {
        alert("An error");
        return;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
   
            <AdMobBanner
                style={styles.bottomBanner}
                bannerSize="fullBanner"
                adUnitID="--My unit id--"
                // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
                testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError={bannerError}
            />

        </View>
    );
}
```

How can I fix this problem or can you recommend me how to add banner admob?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
 // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
```

Comment: I already removed this line but still got same error.